# USB On-the-go MIDI Keyboard with Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7, usb-on-the-go

Has anyone successfully used a MIDI Keyboard (through USB OTG, specifically) with a Nexus 7? (I am not looking for commentary on the particular keyboard, but please state which you have used.)

Comment: Is this a recommendation question? Read the [FAQ] to see what kind of questions that can be asked here :)

Comment: Fair question. It is a compatibility question. I know I am new here, but I am not a complete StackExchange noob.

Comment: Then I suggest you re-edit your question, your first question *...with a Nexus 7 and if so, which one(s)?* is asking for recommendation, second question *another sub-100 dollar MIDI keyboard?* so both are asking for recommendations..BTW one question per post please :)

Comment: I disagree with your interpretation. I am asking about a feature/ability of the nexus 7, which one is a natural adjunct to that. You are correct about 2 questions.

Comment: So maybe you go to some store and test some devices?

Comment: Hmm.. Understood the question incorrectly. I missed the MIDI part, deleted my answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **any *standard Midi* keyboard** with your device. ([src](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=25973235&postcount=1))

There are several keyboards with [Korg](http://www.korg.com/microkey) and [Roland](http://www.rolandus.com/products/details/865). Choice of the device is all yours. But unfortunately there are reports that your nanopad is not working with this as you asked in your original question. ([src](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=28778474&postcount=4))

You may want to verify that with the manufacturer first, before you go for a new one. Once you have a *standard Midi* device (which does not require driver installations), you can use apps like [USB MIDI Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.extreamsd.usbmidimonitor&hl=en) or [Grand Piano](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.als.grandpiano.pro)

---

<sup>Note: You can try eBay for good solutions. Visit a local music store and check compatibility before you buy as [Izzy suggested](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38026/usb-on-the-go-midi-keyboard-with-nexus-7#comment51291_38026)</sup>

Comment: For the record, I can confirm that the Korg nanoPad actually does work with USB-OTG with the Nexus 7 -- sound in Caustic 2 and various midi monitor apps. (I owned one already and just got around to buying a USB-OTG adapter.) I have yet to purchase a keyboard, but I will post here when I find a working one.